# Beginning Web Development with Sinatra: How do I get areas of HTML to respond to mouse clicks

Tags: ruby, user-interface, web, sinatra

Background: I created a [checkers game engine in ruby](https://github.com/greenone1975/draughts), originally with a text based gui, then built [a swing-like desktop gui](https://github.com/greenone1975/checkers_limelight_gui), using Jruby. Now I'm trying to develop [a Sinatra-based web interface](https://github.com/greenone1975/checkers_sinatra) for the view.

One essential task I need to cover is how to communicate board square clicks(such as getting the from and to squares for a movement) to the game engine via the routes. Is there a way to do this using just HTML and CSS or do I need to build-in some javascript to create this functionality? Thanks for any info and advanced apologies if there is ignorance in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript will be your best bet. Assuming you implement the interface with a table or any other html element. Try having a unique identifier for each block if you need different behavior for different block. And then you can use simply jquery to bind to the click event. For example you have a table and each td is a block.

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <td class="block"></td>
   <td class="block"></td>
   <td class="block"></td>
   ... so on..
  </tr>
</table>

$(function(){
 $('.block').click(function(){
   //do something on click.
 });
});
```